# Variable created by const is not accessable before initialization in javaScript. But why there is no error in react create functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```
const BasicFunctionalComponent = props => {
   return (
      <div>
        {constantVariable}
      </div>
   )
}

export default BasicFunctionalComponent

const constantVariable = '**how I am initialized**?'
```

in example above I just create a basic functional component and after exporting it just initialized a constant variable set as a string. then I used it inside JSX above expected to go throw error 'Cannot access 'constantVariable' before initialization'. but all's good

Answer (score 2):

Because `BasicFunctionalComponent` will get called much later. It's basically an asynchronous function from the perspective of this file you showed us. By the time that function is called, `constantVariable` will be defined.

Comment: Also by that time, if constantVariable was not `const`, it could have been mutated. So be careful with using "kind of global" variables like that. Basically try to avoid that in any case.

Comment: Let your functions be pure functions, i think is a good practice even if you're not a pure functional programming dude. Ie. a function returns someting based on it's input. You can trust that the output is always the same if the input is the same. 
The function code should never refer to anything outside the functions own scope or arguments.

Comment: Just to elaborate... very bad:
const b = 1;
function sum(a) {
   return a+b;
}

good:

function sum(a,b) { return a+b; }
// here the function is Pure, it does not need to know anything about the scope surrounding the use of it

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a much more clear example:

```
const fx = () => {
    console.log(v)
}

// fx() // Call it here and it throws error

const v = 1

// fx() // Call it here and it's ok

console.log('Fin!')
```

The reason behind why it does not throw `ReferenceError` is basically because the component function is not called before the initialization of the `constantVariable`.